# How are Ancillary Armor Repairer Blueprints seeded?

Tags: eve-online

How are the new, as of Retribution 1.1, ancillary armor repairer blueprints seeded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly the same as the Ancillary Shield Booster Blueprints are. From [CCP Fozzie's DevBlog](http://community.eveonline.com/devblog.asp?a=blog&nbid=74270):

> Their blueprint copies are found in all the same places where other blueprints for prototype modules such as the ASB can already be acquired.

i.e. spawn as BPCs in exploration sites around k-space. BPCs will vary from 3 to 50 runs and will also drop from officer and commander spawns.